# On iOS, what is the best way at runtime to retrieve the Swift Package version numbers?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I know these are listed in the Package.resolved file. Is the best way to parse that file with a build script and store them? Can I access them directly somehow?

I want to include the package version numbers for each package included in my logging and analytics for bug tracking etc.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this for now by writing a script at build that parses the Package.resolved file and adds the info to the plist with PListBuddy.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same need. I wrote a build-phase to put a simplified version of Package.resolved into the built app's bundle, then a class to make it easy to query for the version of any given package.

The build phase:

```
/* Begin PBXShellScriptBuildPhase section */
07E370312A14208C0035FB2F /* Generate spm_versions.json */ = {
    isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
    buildActionMask = 2147483647;
    files = (
    );
    inputFileListPaths = (
    );
    inputPaths = (
        "$(PROJECT_FILE_PATH)/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved",
    );
    name = "Generate spm_versions.json";
    outputFileListPaths = (
    );
    outputPaths = (
        $TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH/spm_versions.json,
    );
    runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 0;
    shellPath = /bin/sh;
    shellScript = "OUTPUT=\"$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH/spm_versions.json\"\ncat \"$PROJECT_FILE_PATH\"/project.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/swiftpm/Package.resolved | jq '[ .pins[] | { id: .identity, vers: .state.version }]' > \"$OUTPUT\"\n\necho built $OUTPUT\n";
    showEnvVarsInLog = 0;
};
/* End PBXShellScriptBuildPhase section */
```

The code to parse it at runtime:

```
class SPMVersions {

private struct SPMPackage: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let vers: String
}

private static let packages: [SPMPackage] = {
    let logger = print // or whatever
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "spm_versions", ofType: "json") else {
        logger("spm_versions.json not found, should have been created in a build phase")
        return []
    }
    var result = [SPMPackage]()
    do {
        if let jsonData = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath).data(using: .utf8) {
            result = try JSONDecoder().decode([SPMPackage].self, from: jsonData)
        }
    } catch {
        logger("failed to decode spm_versions.json, error: \(error)")
    }
    return result
}()

static func versionOf(_ packageName: String) -> String? {
    packages.first { $0.id == packageName }?.vers
}
```

}

How to use:

`SPMVersions.versionOf("swift-package-manager-google-mobile-ads")`

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Instead, tailor the answer to the question asked. If the questions are exact duplicates of each other, please vote/flag to close instead.